# {“Input string was not in a correct format.”} : oracle stored procedure error

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-manageddataaccess

Stored procedure

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY LOGGER IS PROCEDURE LOG
        (abcd OUT INT,abcd1 INT,abcd2 INT,abcd3 VARCHAR2,abcd4 VARCHAR2,abcd5 DATE,
        abcd6 VARCHAR2,abcd7 VARCHAR2,abcd8 VARCHAR2,abcd9 VARCHAR2,abcd10 VARCHAR2,
        abcd10 VARCHAR2,abcd11 VARCHAR2,abcd12 VARCHAR2, abcd13  VARCHAR2)
        IS BEGIN

        INSERT INTO LOG    (abcd,abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8  
 abcd9,abcd10,abcd11,abcd12,abcd13)                                      

        VALUES (0,CAST (LOG.abcd AS NUMBER (10)),CAST (LOG.abcd1 AS NUMBER (10)),
    LOG.abcd2,LOG.abcd3,LOG.abcd4,LOG.abcd5,LOG.abcd6,LOG.abcd7,LOG.abcd8,
    LOG.abcd9,LOG.abcd10,LOG.abcd11,LOG.abcd12);

    SELECT LOG_SEQ.CURRVAL INTO LOG.abcd FROM DUAL;
    END LOG;
```

logging.cs file

```
     private int ExecuteWriteLogStoredProcedure(LogEntry logEntry, Database db, DbTransaction transaction)
    {
        OracleAdapter adapter = new OracleAdapter();
        var con = adapter.OpenConnection();
        var cmd = adapter.CreateSpCommand(con, this.writeLogStoredProcName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd", OracleDbType.Int32, 4,ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd1", OracleDbType.Int32, logEntry.abcd1,ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd2", OracleDbType.Int16, logEntry.abcd2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd3", OracleDbType.Varchar2,32,ParameterDirection.Input,false,(byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd3.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd4", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 256, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd4);        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd5", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, logEntry.TimeStamp,ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd6", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd6);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd7", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd7);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd8", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 256, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd8);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd9", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd9);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd10", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd10);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd11", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd11);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd12", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1500, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.abcd12);
        if (this.Formatter != null)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("formattedmessage", OracleDbType.Varchar2, this.Formatter.Format(logEntry),ParameterDirection.Input);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("formattedmessage", OracleDbType.Varchar2, (object)logEntry.Message, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters[0].Value, (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }
```

I'm getting error in

```
          cmd.Parameters.Add("abcd2", OracleDbType.Int32, logEntry.abcd2, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

The value of logEntry.abcd2 is 0x000000000 and priority is not null in my table . How to solve this error? Please help . Any clue will be helpful .

Comment: The second parameter should be _abcd1_ not _abcd_

Comment: Also, you try to convert to an integer the last parameter, but your output parameter is the first one. It should be _cmd.Parameters[0].Value_

Comment: @Steve thanks for reply but now I'm facing {"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

Comment: any suggestion to solve this error?? @Steve

Comment: Not sure why you need to CAST. Parameters abcd1 and abcd2 are already numbers.

Comment: @Steve cause abcd is object of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection and I want to convert it to int value but getting error

Comment: @Steve cause abcd is object of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection and I want to convert it to int value but getting error Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' to type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection'.

Comment: any clue to solve this